# How can a member with reputation of 1 have many badges?

Tags: discussion, account-suspension

I've happened to see [this guy's profile](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1358004/viral-shah?tab=badges). His reputation is 1 but he's got a lot of badges. Did he get downvoted **that** heavily?!

Comment: Do you happen to have a link to "this guy's profile"? Without actually  seeing it, we can only guess.

Comment: Link the "guy's profile", please.

Comment: He could have placed a lot of bounties.

Comment: A lot of badges have nothing to do with reputation. Off the top of my head, Announcer, Booster, Analytical, Fanatic, Enthusiast, Autobiographer....

Comment: The user you linked to has 795 rep. You got downvoted for not including a link, making your question impossible to answer.

Comment: So the user *was* suspended, and their suspension had just ended a few minutes ago. Apparently, it takes a while for a user to get back their reputation even after their suspension is over. If you look at it now it has been recalculated to 795. Case closed.

Comment: Hope that by now you understand the meaning of downvotes on Meta?

Answer (score 12):

Reputation of suspended members is displayed as 1 during the period of suspension. Once the suspension is lifted, the reputation goes back to where it was before.

Comment: One possibility. If this is the case, there will be a **temporarily suspended for** banner on the user's profile page.

Comment: @Dennis Nope. Now suspension as far I could see. Otherwise I wouldn't ask.    :)

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn We don't even know what user he's referring to yet, do we?

Comment: @Bart We do now, check the question.

Comment: @Bart: He just added the link, so you'll need to refresh.

Comment: @Bart Yes you do if you read the post. The *edited* post.   ;)

Comment: So apparently, this Web Sockets auto-updating thing doesn't work. Who knew?

Comment: Hmm, point taken :D I was worried about some unknown mod-powers there for a moment.

Comment: Ah, it was just a lag. I reloaded the page and assumed that one a potential ban is lifted the score would return to the original value directly. Hmm... Mistery solved.

Comment: @PopularDemand: Thanks. I never figured out if my brain is too slow for my fingers or if my fingers are too slow for my brain.

Comment: This answer is not really accurate. First, the reputation **is** 1 by all means, not just *displayed* as 1. Second, when the suspension is over (not lifted, when set the mod choose for how long so he does not have to manually lift it) the reputation is recalculated from scratch, and it won't always goes back to where is was before since the user can get votes (either up or down) on his posts while suspended plus posts can be deleted during this time.